# How to change date dynamically for each element in an Array

Tags: java

Hi I have asked same type of   question but here i am asking with more information to avoid confusion.

I can see where is the problem, the `DateOldStr` variable is setting empty before hand. but i want to know how can i Dynamically change the value of 
`DateOldStr`  inside the for loop.

```
public class Testarray {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String[] LoopArray = new String[3];


    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss");
    String DateOldStr = "";
    String[] anArray = {
            "001,"+ DateOldStr +",F,162948.00,A,5153.68366,N,00026.29111,W,3.863,136.93,,1,0,0.00%,,;",
            "001,"+ DateOldStr +",,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,8.855,121.16,,1,0,0.00%,,;",
            "001,"+ DateOldStr +",,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,9.855,121.16,,2,0,0.00%,,;"
    };

    for (int i =0 ;i <anArray.length;i++) {

        String  DateToStr = format.format(new Date());

                System.out.println(anArray[i]); // Here I need to pass new Date  but not happening.
        try{
        //  shwo array element every 10sc so that it gets current date and time.
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){

        }
    }
}
```

So when i a executing this, i get this out put ,but as you can see the Date stamp is are empty because i am setting them `String DateOldStr = "";`

```
001,,F,162948.00,A,5153.68366,N,00026.29111,W,3.863,136.93,,1,0,0.00%,,;
001,,,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,8.855,121.16,,1,0,0.00%,,;
001,,,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,9.855,121.16,,2,0,0.00%,,;
```

Comment: What is the question here? How is it different from your previous question?

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names should start with lowercase. Also, do you have a good reason to use the **obsolete `Date` class** rather than the classes from the Java Time API available in the `java.time` package? You should use that instead.

Comment: If a solution helped you, don't hesitate to accept it, do make this post done ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could do a string replaceAll to swap in the date.

```
public class Testarray {
public static void main(String args[]) {
String[] LoopArray = new String[3];


SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss");
String DateOldStr = "";
String[] anArray = {
        "001,insertdateoldstr,F,162948.00,A,5153.68366,N,00026.29111,W,3.863,136.93,,1,0,0.00%,,;",
        "001,insertdateoldstr,,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,8.855,121.16,,1,0,0.00%,,;",
        "001,insertdateoldstr,,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,9.855,121.16,,2,0,0.00%,,;"
};

for (int i =0 ;i <anArray.length;i++) {

    String  DateToStr = format.format(new Date());
    anArray[i]=anArray[i].replaceAll("insertdateoldstr",DateToStr);   
    System.out.println(anArray[i]); // Here I need to pass new Date  but not happening.

    try{
    //  shwo array element every 10sc so that it gets current date and time.
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could of course use `String.format`. Note that you must replace the percent sign near the end of the strings with "%%", since the percent sign indicates the beginning of a formatter argument.

```
String[] arr = {
    "001,%s,F,162948.00,A,5153.68366,N,00026.29111,W,3.863,136.93,,1,0,0.00%%,,;",
    "001,%s,,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,8.855,121.16,,1,0,0.00%%,,;",
    "001,%s,,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,9.855,121.16,,2,0,0.00%%,,;"
};

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMddHHmmss");
Arrays.stream(anArray)
    .forEach(t -> {
        System.out.println(String.format(t, LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter)));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As you may understand, each line is executed one after the other, so if you put `DateOldStr` you can't just change it's value and wait for a change in your array, there is no kind of *binding*

What you can do is insert the `now's date` in the loop using a `StringBuilder` which allows you to `insert` a `String` at index 4, also use `LocalDateTime` as it's the latest `time api`, rather then the obsolete `date` package

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMddHHmmss");
String[] anArray = {
        "001,,F,162948.00,A,5153.68366,N,00026.29111,W,3.863,136.93,,1,0,0.00%,,;",
        "001,,,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,8.855,121.16,,1,0,0.00%,,;",
        "001,,,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,9.855,121.16,,2,0,0.00%,,;"
};

LocalDateTime dateNow;
StringBuilder sb;

for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {

    dateNow = LocalDateTime.now();
    sb = new StringBuilder(anArray[i]);
    sb.insert(4, dateNow.format(format));
    anArray[i] = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(anArray[i]);

    try { Thread.sleep(10000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
001,181102113025,F,162948.00,A,5153.68366,N,00026.29111,W,3.863,136.93,,1,0,0.00%,,;
001,181102113035,,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,8.855,121.16,,1,0,0.00%,,;
001,181102113045,,F,163018.00,A,5153.67529,N,00026.27327,W,9.855,121.16,,2,0,0.00%,,;
```

---

- Following Java naming conventions, use `lowerCamelCase` for variable, parameters, ...
- Never let an `catch` block empty, at least use `Exception.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Hi Thanks
for DateTimeFormatter , which Java library shall i use ?
I see there is lot of document on this but none of them saying which library

Comment: @alammd no library , it's in the JRE like all the rest, just `import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`